# adding color to pre block

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a script on GM that I would like to add color to on the info page. I tried copying the pre area with all the spans and all the style's independently but userscripts doesn't let me add style tags. Is there a site or util that I can paste my code and it will color it with inline css coloring?

Comment: The question is not completely clear; a "before" and "after" would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not 100% sure if I understand what you are asking for, but if you are thinking about syntax highlighters in Javascript, [there are quite a few out there](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=javascript+syntax+highl&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+syntax+highlighter).

If you want an online tool that adds highlighting for you and outputs html, [here is a nice one](http://wiki.xmlhack.ru/jScript/). If you want a web service, then I´m sorry, I don´t know of any, but it would be awesome if someone did.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately userscripts.org doesn't even let me put inline styling inside the description

Answer (score 0):

> but userscripts doesn't let me add style tags

Have you seen the [GM_addStyle](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle) API? I think it will do what you want.